# What is constexpr in C++?

Tags: c++, constants, constexpr

I am really confused about a `constexpr` concept, as I have read `constexpr` is evaluated at compile time, so it is useful for performance optimization versus normal `const`.

```
constexpr int i = 0;
constexpr int& ri = i;
```

The above code returns an error "invalid initialization of reference of type 'int&' from expression of type 'const int'", why?

Also, the next code has an error:

```
constexpr int i = 0;
constexpr int* ri = &i;
```

If I replaced the `constexpr` keyword with `const`, all above worked correctly.

Comment: you forgot const qualifier `constexpr int const& ri = i;`. `constexpr int i = 0;` also declare `i` as const... [demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/2oc2VMdtymZ93ANa)

Comment: "if I replaced the constexpr word with const all above worked correctly." A `const int*` essentially means `(const int)*` (except you can't use parentheses that way). A `constexpr int*` means `constepxr (int*)` (ditto note).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Re

> **”** if I replaced the constexpr word with const all above worked correctly."

A `const int*` essentially means `(const int)*`, except that you can't use parentheses that way. A `constexpr int*` means `constepxr (int*)` (ditto note).

This is because `constexpr` is not part of the type, you can't name the type `constexpr int`, say, while `const` is part of the type.

Instead of

```
constexpr int i = 0;
constexpr int& ri = i;
```

which attempts to declare a `constexpr` reference to non-`const`, just write

```
constexpr int i = 0;
constexpr int const& ri = i;
```

You can read that backwards as `ri` is a reference to a `const` `int` which is `constexpr` (evaluated at compile time).

---

**Addendum**:

It ¹appears that C++14 requires local non-`static` `constexpr` objects to have **automatic storage duration**, modulo the *as-if* rule for optimization.

To cater for this, i.e. to make the code portable across compilers, if the above declarations appear locally in a function, add `static` to ensure static storage duration for the object that one refers to:

```
void oops()
{
    static constexpr int i = 0;      // Necessary with some compilers.
    constexpr int const& ri = i;
}
```

Otherwise it may not compile with e.g. g++, and it's *probably* what the C++14 and C++11 standards require, by omission of suitable constraints on `constexpr`.

<sup>*Notes:*

¹ See the [discussion of R. Sahu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42107945/464581).</sup>

Answer (score 14):

```
constexpr int i = 0;
constexpr int  * ri = &i;
```

The second line is a problem because the pointer does not point to a `const` object. The pointer itself is `const`.

Using

```
constexpr int i = 0;
constexpr int const * ri = &i;
```

solves that problem. However, that will be still a problem if the variables are defined in a function scope.

```
constexpr int i = 0;
constexpr int const* ri = &i;

int main() {}
```

is a valid program.

```
void foo()
{
   constexpr int i = 0;
   constexpr int const* ri = &i;
}

int main() {}
```

is not a valid program.

Here's what the C++11 standard has to say about *address constant expression*:

> **5.19 Constant expressions**
>
> 3 ..
>   An *address constant expression* is a prvalue core constant expression of pointer type that evaluates to the address of an object with static storage duration, to the address of a function, or to a null pointer value, or a prvalue core constant expression of type `std::nullptr_t`.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the function scope problem. I see that g++ behaves as you state, but MSVC accepts that allegedly invalid code. g++ says that `i` isn't constant, but allows its use as array size (and not a VLA). That is inconsistent. g++ accepts the code with `static` added. Are you sure that you're not reporting a compiler quirk (bug) as a rule of the language? If it is a rule, what is it?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I think RSahu is right one cannot supply address that is runtime dependent to constexpr pointer. Imagine the situation when the foo is called recursively. `ri` should get different value at each recursion level, but how many recursion levels are there? It may depend on runtime value...

Comment: @W.F.: I would not offhand think that argument would hold, because there's no sense in giving `i`  a different adress determined at run time, but with a value known at compile time. That's just idiocy. If there is such a rule in the current language definition, then that's clearly a defect in the standard. So I'm interested in what the (alleged) rule is.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf yup you're right I forgot that it's constexpr :) yes it is interesting indeed...

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, Added a reference to the standard that corroborates my statement.

Comment: @RSahu: It could corroborate your statement if (and this would be a defect) a `constexpr` object does not always have static storage duration. So we need to look at that. But I need some breakfast, medicine and coffee. :)

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, I didn't see anything in section 5.19 of the standard about the storage duration of `constexpr` objects. Whether that is a defect or not, I am not sure.

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13867690/4324224) looks like a nice discussion on the static vs constexpr local objects...

Comment: @RSahu: I've searched through the C++ 14 standard and perused google results such as (http://stackoverflow.com/a/38853356/464581), and it seems as you're right about the formal: a `constexpr` object needs not have static storage duration, and probably a local non-`static` one is required to behave *as-if* it's of automatic storage duration. This supports (1) `constexpr` objects that are not really constant because they have `mutable` parts, (2) per translation-unit optimization where an non-ODR used non-`static` `constexpr` object is removed, and (3) just wasting programmers' time. A defect.

Comment: Thanks for noting this, I learned something new today. I thought that kind of nonsense only started with C++14 and bloomed with C++17. Non-constant `constepxr` objects. Grumble, grumble... Argh!

Answer (score 5):

As you said, `constexpr` is evaluated at **compile time**. So the value must be evaluable when compiling.

For example:

```
constexpr int i = 0;
constexpr int& ri = i;
```

For first line, 0 is evaluable when compiling, its value is 0.

But for second line, compiler needs address of `i` to do the assignment, which is determined at runtime. So this line will fail.

Comment: Is a constexpr uses only for performance optimization versus a const?

Comment: @BassamNajeeb It can be used to replace macros, and hard-coded literals. For example, you can wrap macros and literals into `constexpr` functions, and provide a meaningful name for them.

Answer (score 1):

Here are my 2 cents:

The `constexpr` feature defines computation that happens during the compile time. Reasonable question:

- Does it make sense to allow **any computation**?

Reasonable answer:

- **No**, because this would require a lot of machinery, resources, etc right inside the compiler while there is no direct need for that.

Because of that standard allows pretty limited set of features inside the `constexpr` code. One may argue why exactly this set and not something more? Well, later on the standard may evolve and allow more.