# Explicit instantiation of function template with `using` or otherwise

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, template-instantiation

`using` for class templates works like a charm

```
 template<class T,int N>
 struct VecNT{ T arr[N]; };

 using Vec5d = VecNT<double,5>;     // doing great job!
```

but it seems it does not work for functions at all

```
 template<class T,int N>
 T sumNT(T* xs){ T sum=0; for(int i=0;i<N;i++){sum+=xs[i];}; return sum; };

 using sum5d = sumNT<double,5>;  
    // ERROR: sumNT<double,5> does not name a type

 using sum5d(double* xs) = sumNT<double,5>(T* xs);
    // ERROR: expected nest-name-specifier before 'sum5d'
```

So how to make `sum5d` as an specialized/instantiated alias for `sumNT<double,5>` ?

Comment: Have you tried e.g. `auto sum5d = &sumNT<double,5>;`? This should make a function pointer which can be used then like a function ID. (Or `double (*sum5d)(double*) = &sumNT<double,5>;`?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just declare a function pointer for your alias:

```
template<class T,int N>
T sumNT(T* xs){ T sum=0; for(int i=0;i<N;i++){sum+=xs[i];}; return sum; };

constexpr auto sum5d = &sumNT<double,5>;  

int main()
{
    double d[5];
    sum5d(d);
}
```

GCC and Clang manage to optimise away the function pointer and call the original function directly, MSVC doesn't: https://godbolt.org/z/1_fs83

Comment: thanks. Just for curiosity what  `constexpr` exactly does here? Does it help the optimization (like to bake the constant template parameters, and optimize out the function pointer?

Comment: `constexpr` is for a constant that the compiler can generate at compile time. Ofent (and in this case) compilers will generate the same code with just `const`, the main difference is that if you mark something as `constexpr` which the compiler can't generate at compile time it will fail to compile. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14116003/difference-between-constexpr-and-const and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42107744/what-is-constexpr-in-c