# Using objects with mutable fields inside constexpr functions

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, constexpr, mutable

A constant expression cannot access a mutable sub-object. This is in [expr.const#4.8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.const#4.8)

> An object or reference is *usable in constant expressions* if it is ... a non-mutable subobject ...

And there is a [nice question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38851469/7325599) about it. (Both recent GCC and Clang properly reject the example from there).

But is there any restrictions on using objects (both starting and ending their lifetime) with mutable fields in `constexpr` functions? Please consider the example:

```
struct S {
    mutable int i = 2;
};

auto f = []{
    constexpr S s;
    s.i = 3;
    return s.i;
};

// ok everywhere
int x = f();
// error in GCC
constexpr int y = f();
```

Here the initialization of `y` succeeds in Clang, but fails in GCC with the error:

```
  in 'constexpr' expansion of 'f.<lambda()>()'
error: mutable 'S::i' is not usable in a constant expression
```

Online demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/qbfY6jfbe

On the one side, `mutable` subobject is indeed used. But on the other side, it shall behave as normal not-const object, which is allowed inside `constexpr` functions.

Which compiler is right here?